# manipulating nested data 2

Tags: r, function, data-manipulation

I am new to r, and I am having some trouble manipulating the data in the way I need it for my analysis. I would be grateful if anyone could help, because this is essential for my research.

I already asked a similar question but the answer I got did not fully address my problem, I will try to be more clear this time to see if anyone can help.

my data looks something like this:

```
df<- data.frame(
"Reporter" = c("USA", "USA", "USA", "USA", "USA","USA"),
"Partner" = c( "EU", "EU","EU","EU", "EU","EU"), 
"Product.cat" = c("1", "11", "111", "112", "12", "2"), 
"Product Description" = c("Food", "Fruit", "Apple", 
"Banana", "Meat", "Manifactured"),
"Year" = c(1970, 1970, 1970, 1970, 1970, 1970), 
"trade value" = c( 100, 50, 30, 20, 50, 220), 
stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

I have country-year observations about trade. 
The vector *'product.cat'* indicates what kind of commodity is exported. The more digits the *product.cat* has, the more the trade information is disaggregated. 
For example *product.cat.* 111 (eg. apple) and 112 (e.g. bananas) are sub-product categories of product category 11 (e.g. fruit). 
The same holds for the higher levels of aggregation. Product category 11 (fruit) is a subcategory of *product.cat* 1(food) together with *product.cat* 12 (meat).
To note that data in lower categories is nested in higher level of aggregation. Hence the value of *product.cat* 11 (50) is equal to the value of *product.cat* 111 (30) + *product.cat* 112 (20).

To do my analysis I need to identify those values that are not reported at the most disaggregated possible level - i.e. **I need to identify the data not reported at the 3 digit level.**

My problem is that for some country-year observation I have data reported accurately at all levels of aggregation (e.g. 1,11,111,112) while for others i only have data at the higher level of aggregation (e.g. 12 and 2). For instance, in my example, I only have *product.cat* 12 (meat), but not data on what kind of meat *product.cat* 121(pork), *product.cat* 122 (veal). 
Similarly, in the example, data on *product.cat* 2 (manufacturing), is not reported at lower levels. 
we do not know whether is *product.cat* 21 (clothing) or *product.cat* 22 (wood products).

In other words, I have data reported at the 2 digit (12) or first digit level (2) that could be reported at the 3 digit level. **To note that every category should be disaggregated at the 3 level digit**

- *What I would like to do is to find a way to individuate all the data* ***exclusively*** *reported at a higher level of aggregation and* ***change their product.cat name adding an "m" to the end.***
- *After manipulation the* product.cat 12 should become* **12m** *to indicate that data was reported only at the 2nd digit. 
  Similarly I would like to identify exports that are reported* **only** *at the first digit. product.cat 2 should become* **2mm** *to reflect that the data was reported only at the first digit.*

To be sure, only the data for which I have information exclusively at a higher level of aggregation - i.e. in the example 12 and 2 - should include "m"s. 
For instance, in the example, I do not want to have 1mm, since I have data at a lower level of aggregation (11,12). Similarly, I do not want to have 11m, because I have data at lower levels of aggregation (111,112). What I would like to have is 12m and 2mm because the data is reported only at a higher level of aggregation (12 and 2).

I know that this is a very specific question but I would really appreciate if anyone could help.

**Note**: in the real dataset, due to for measurement errors, the sum of the disaggregated values do not always perfectly add up to the higher level of aggregation. (for instance, 111+112 can be > 11). Hence, ideally to solve the issue the, I am looking to a function that is able to specify when to add the m based on the number of digits divided by country, partner, year, rather than the sum of the traded value.

I really thank everyone that could give me a help with this, it would be a huge step forward for my research.

---- UPDATE

i have been working on this function, but it does not seem to do what I am looking for. Maybe someone can find out what is going wrong

```
fillLevel <- function(x, width = 3, fill = "m"){
sp <- split(x, substr(x, 1, 1))
sp <- lapply(seq_along(sp), function(i){
n <- nchar(sp[[i]])
if(all(n < 3)){
  j <- which(n == max(n))
  sp[[i]][j] <- gsub(" ", "m", formatC(sp[[i]][j], width = -3))
}
sp[[i]]
})
unname(unlist(sp))
}

df <- df%>% mutate(prdcat2 = fillLevel(df$Product.cat.))
```

Best

Comment: if you turn your categories to numbers so 12 as opposed to '12' (the character 12), then you can use the floor function. floor(x/100) > 0 only if the product has three digits.  Categorize those and then floor(x/10) > 0 & floor(x/100) = 0 for two digits.  You can play with this idea and get better ways to do it, but I think this is a useful hint.

Comment: There is an error in the data provided where Banana is listed as 122 even though it should be 112 and Veal is Product.cat. 122.

Comment: yes, @camnesia, you are right sorry for this I have done the correction

Comment: @aginensky, yes this could be an idea, the issue is that the actual data the category start from 0, 00, 001. Would you be able to specify precisely how i could use a floor function in this case?

Comment: hmm.  Why not use strsplit and length ?  As in " length(strsplit("00","")[[1]]) "  (returns 2)

Comment: not sure I understand what you mean, would you mind elaborating?  I am new to r and I find it difficult to follow... thank you again and sorry for the disturb

Answer (score 0):

This should work. Note that the column names with spaces in them are slightly changed ("Product cat." to "Product.cat." etc.)

```
df <- df %>%
      mutate(Product.cat. = case_when(nchar(Product.cat.) == 1 ~ paste0(Product.cat.,'mm'),
                                nchar(Product.cat.) == 2 ~ paste0(Product.cat.,'m'),
                                TRUE ~ Product.cat.))
```

Comment: hello, thanks for looking after this. Unfortunately, it does not do what I am looking for. your scripts adds m's to all non 3 dgt cases... while I would like to add the **m's** only when I do not have data at the 3 digit level (i.e. 12m and 2mm) while **it should not attach the m when I  have data at the more disaggregated level (1mm, 11m)** do you have any suggestion to individuate only the former cases? thank you very much.

Comment: Any idea on how to individuate the key product cat's for which I have to add an m? I am really helpless and the moment, and it is really fundamental to solve this problem for me to go forward...